# Copy background color from one cell to cell in separate sheet using ms-excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy background color for example sheetA cell A1 to
sheet B A1.

The cell A1 is using conditional formatting, I can copy simple but not with conditional formatting enabled.

Here is the code

```
Public Sub CopyColor()
Dim PeopleSheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetSht As Worksheet

'Define what our source sheet and target sheet are
Set PeopleSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("People")
Set ProcessSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Process")
Set TechnologySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Technology")
Set BusinessSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Business")

Set TargetSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")





Set s1 = PeopleSheet.Range("G3:G9").FormatConditions(1)

Set t1 = TargetSht.Range("F15:F21")

t1.Interior.Color = s1.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
```

Last line `t1.Interior.Color = s1` give error `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`

**Update**

[image]

**UPDATE 2** @Ralph

This is the result of before and after application of code, respectively.

[image]
[image]

Only `f15` is effected not others?

**UPDATE 3**

This is the best evidence I can come up, when I run the VB it just select the target cells and ask me to PASTE the results. So the bottom left status bar in video.[image]

Comment: Kindly help community, none of the responders have given correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

To copy over only the format (which includes the conditional format) from `A1` on `sheetA` to `A1` on `sheetB` you can use the following:

```
Worksheets("sheetA").Range("A1").Copy
Worksheets("sheetB").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

If you don't want to give up on the current conditional formatting on cell `A1` on `sheetB` and just want to add the conditional formatting from `A1` on `sheetA` you can also use `xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats`. Yet, then the value will get copied over and you'll have to store that (to write it back again afterwards). So, the complete code in this case might be something like this:

```
Dim strTemp As String

strTemp = Worksheets("sheetB").Range("A1").Formula
Worksheets("sheetA").Range("A1").Copy
Worksheets("sheetB").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
Worksheets("sheetB").Range("A1").Formula = strTemp
```

### Update:

Apparently, the sheet names and the ranges have changed (in the update). So, the updated code should be:

```
Dim varTemp As Variant

varTemp = Worksheets("Summary").Range("F15:F21").Formula
Worksheets("People").Range("G3:G9").Copy
Worksheets("Summary").Range("F15:F21").PasteSpecial xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
Worksheets("Summary").Range("F15:F21").Formula = varTemp
```

Note, that you want to store several formulas at once. Hence, you'll need an array variable to hold it and not a string variable anymore.

I am not sure what you are doing. But it certainly works for me (as it should):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I get an error can you see my range syntax as correct?

Comment: For copy and paste you can use only a connecting range. In your case you seem to have two cells you want to copy over at once: `G3` and `G9` (but not all the cells between the two). So, you'll have to do two copies and pastes: one for `G3` to `F15` and another for `G9` to `F21`.

Comment: No, Ralph I want range like `G3 to G9`, saying it like `G3:G9` gives error.

Comment: Next time, please immediately post the relevant ranges and sheet names (if you are not yet able to correctly adjust the given VBA code) so we don't have to waste our times.

Comment: I apologize, I thought specifying range would be trivial.

Comment: The code runs with no error, but effect is not complete, see update.

Comment: It works if i removed `Worksheets("Summary").Range("F15:F21").Formula = varTemp` but then it copies the value from "People" sheet, i just want background.

Comment: Not sure what you are doing. But it certainly works for me (as it should). Have a look at the updated solution. I guess you have made yet another adaptation which doesn't work out as expected. Yet, we can only help you debug what you've given us.

Comment: The animation is very useful, I have same results but the funny thing is that when I run the code, the target cells is prompting for PASTE action. Please see update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115609/discussion-between-asadz-and-ralph).

Comment: I have debug and see code working perfect with single cell and not applying range `G3:G9.`

Answer (score 2):

Why not take out the DisplayFormat and leave it like this:

`t1.Interior.Color = s1.Interior.Color`

Answer (score 1):

This should work - at least as I understand what you're asking

```
Set s1 = PeopleSheet.Range("G3:G9").DisplayFormat
Set t1 = TargetSht.Range("F15:F21")

t1.Interior.Color = s1.Interior.Color
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't it just black out the target cells instead

Comment: What do you mean? That's what you were asking for - and your example shows. It removes runtime error and copies conditional format color to target cells. What do you want it to do? I'd suggest updating your question - and code

Comment: It doesn't work , please show If it does for you. For me it pastes black background cells only.

Comment: You need to change the cells to correspond to your data - we're just using your ranges from above. You're wasting everyone's time here without posting proper data

Comment: You seems confused. I have put entire gif for that, what more you want